# How to find a word in text and read the corresponding two lines?

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsstring

I would like to find a specific word and read the corresponding two lines.

EX :

> apple
>
> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
>
> samsung
>
> qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
>
> wwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
>
> nokia
>
> ttttttttttttttttt
>
> zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

If I search for "apple" I would like to get `apple` and the second line also (`yyyyyyyy`) . I tried with the code below but it's not working :

```
NSString *contentString = [NSString stringWithContentOfFile:path/to/your/file.txt encoding:textEncoding error:&error];

if (!error) {
    NSRange range = [contentString rangeOfString:yourKeyword];

......
```

Comment: Have you tried using Regular Expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Get the file in a string, and separate it with newlines. Then, find the line you want and get the next two lines too. If I want to search for `Dian007`, something like-

```
// for myfile.txt
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfile" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSArray *myArray = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

// since we want two lines more, don't count last two elements
for(int i = 0; i < ([myArray count] - 2); ++i) { 
  if([[myArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Dian007"]) {
    // get i-th, (i + 1)th and (i + 2)th lines here

    // For example, to print the lines...
    NSLog(@"first item := \"%@\"", [myArray objectAtIndex:i]);
    NSLog(@"second item := \"%@\"", [myArray objectAtIndex:(i + 1)]);
    NSLog(@"third item := \"%@\"", [myArray objectAtIndex:(i + 2)]);
  }
}
```

Comment: @ KK 

NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL]

i am getting "use of undeclared identifier ´path"

Comment: You have to make sure that the file is in your application bundle. If you are able to get the contents of the file in a NSString anyways, you can proceed with the further code, from the `NSArray *myArray = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];` line.

Comment: Thanks KK .. but i am getting an error 


NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL] i am getting "use of undeclared identifier ´path"

Comment: Do you have the text file in your app bundle? ... In your code, have you tried logging `contentString`? What does it show?

Comment: can i have ur mail id .. i will send my code ... if u need privacy ... just ping a mail to :dilipanand1986@gmail.com

its my project , i am struggling in this last step .

Comment: one more doubt 
for(int i = 0; i < ([myArray count] - 2); ++i) { 
  if([[myArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Dian007"]) {
    NSLog(@"%d", myarray);
  }
}

is this right where i can see the output ??

Comment: Can we chat about 1.5 hours form now?

Comment: really thanks KK ... 
// since we want two lines more, don't count last two elements
for(int i = 0; i < ([myArray count] - 2); ++i) { 
  if([[myArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Dian007"]) {
 {
NSLog(@"\n\n the string %@", myArray");

is this statement is right

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < ([myArray count] - 2); ++i) { 
  if([[myArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Dian007"]) 

"while step debugginhg" its giving "stopped after step"

Comment: Looks like `myArray` is `nil`. Can you tell how are you including the text file in the project?

Comment: http://www.filehost.ws/47rjobt7nex0

i attached my simple project with ur code .. just look to it ... really thanks for answering my all question :) :)

Comment: I am unable to get your project. Can you just post the code (pastebin or gist etc) for the .h and .m file of the class in which you are doing this work?

Comment: Since you are just dragging the file into your project, you need only `pathForResource:ofType:` and not `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory`. If you want to use the second version, you need to actually create a directory for it. See this link for more detail:http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/31256-nsbundle-pathforresource-indirectory-gives-nil.html . This should be the correct case if `NSLog(@"%@", content);` does not print the contents of the text file.